# How to define displayed area of map control at startup in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

This might be little bit novice but, how can i set initial displayed area of map control in wp7? I mean, when i changed zoom level from properties, it shows closer look to the map. But i don't know how to make it display europe at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SetView method of the Map control, passing to it the location you want to center on and a particular zoom level :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588591(v=vs.92).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588382(v=vs.92).aspx